# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002):in cplesk

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cpanel, plesk

I am using Codeignitor and when it was correctly running on cpanel but when i hosted it to plesk . Following error occured
[image]

My databse.php is

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    //'hostname' => '148.66.154.149:3306',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',   
         'dbport' => '3306',
    'username' => 'supergrandgenes',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'exam_guide',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Please help why it is not working on plesk

Comment: Please post errors as text, not as images with tiny fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your `hostname` , `username` , `password` , `database` entries as they might differ depending on the host. 
All these details are available in your cPanel.